# Find co-ordinates of points where curve degree changes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics, coordinate-systems, least-squares

If I have list of co-ordinates which defines a complex curve. I need to find points where the resulting curve changes degree or curvature. 
By Finding these points, I am trying to fit quadratic curve on the input curve points.

Comment: Please upload the list and explain what you attempted a bit clearer. It will help the community to assist you further

Comment: Can't you fit a quadratic curve without knowing where your curve changes degree or curvature? I don't see how knowing those locations helps you to fit a quadratic curve to your points.

Comment: It is required to smoothn boundary of segmentation of an image. Data of segmentation boundary is not smooth hence for that I am using least square fitting. But for hole closed boundary least square of specific degree is not possible. Random smoothness will make feature lose. So for that points where slopes are changing are required.

Comment: Did you consider parametric splines ?